# Android Contacts

Tags: android

I have a java code for contacts app in Android and it needs a package named

import com.google.android.collect.Maps;

I am not able to figure out how to include this in eclipse so that I can go ahead working with this app.

Answer (score 2):

See Adding an External Library (.jar) using Eclipse: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary

Comment: Can you help me with finding this jar file.

Comment: I tried searching a lot but couldn't finally get anything

Comment: A search on "google maps jar" returns this for example: http://www.filecrop.com/google-maps.jar.html

Comment: Thank You...I'll check if this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this comes from a cut of [Google Guava Library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com).

Source code here:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/com/google/android/collect